# How to resolve Visual Studio Code "the window is no longer responding" error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, crash

I am new to VS Code. I started using it as it was the recommended IDE to best explore React.

Everything was smooth until now when I am no longer able to launch it. I tried launching it from the Quick Access link as well as using command line, the first response I received was "The window has crashed".

I checked support forums and cleared the AppData as per suggestions and retried. Now I am getting the message "the window is no longer responding".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems a bug. Try removing the folder from the root folder, create a new folder again and then try to launch again.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, are you suggesting that I move my code to a new folder and then try again?

Comment: Yes. Try this, and also if this doesn't work, delete the folder you just created to learn React, and recreate it.

Comment: If the problem still persists, try reinstalling VS Code

Comment: Reinstalling VS code didn't solve it